# How to make blog title page dynamic?

Tags: php, html, blogs

I'm using an static HTML template to create my website but my problem is that I don't know how is it possible to make a page that anything I write there would be placed in blog title page and the older ones goes under it automatically and even the rest moves in another page. also one to create the entire articles in there.

example of pages
https://www.mediafire.com/?i13i6uprl5kbzj8 , 
http://www.mediafire.com/view/ciok7d4dn24bohn/blog.PNG

Comment: I get what you are trying to say (from the title), but your entire question just leaves me completely blank. What are you trying to say?

Comment: @Epodax is right. Explain your situation with some code.

Comment: I guess your problem is, once you set a title, all blog posts get that title. Unfortunately there is no way to help you without seeing code. You say you have static HTML, you'll probably need to change to PHP and database.